# Get the measured value

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

I have forge on a web page with a modal I created. The behavior of the program should be: the user presses a Button it starts the measurer tool and it gets the measurement.

However, I struggle to get the distance that have been measured and I couldn't find anything that helps online

Appreciate your help,

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of all measurements with this function :

```
const measureExtension = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Measure');
var measureList = measureExtension.getMeasurementList();
```

This will give you an array of measures that look like this :

```
[{
    "from": "Vertex",
    "to": "Vertex",
    "distance": "260.7 mm",
    "deltaX": "29.4 mm",
    "deltaY": "14.8 mm",
    "deltaZ": "258.7 mm",
    "angle": "0.0 °",
    "area": "NaN",
    "arc": "0.0 mm",
    "location": "X: 0.0 mm\nY: 0.0 mm\nZ: 0.0 mm",
    "text": "",
    "unitType": "mm",
    "precision": 1,
    "picks": [
        {
            "intersection": {
                "x": 35.7674868316803,
                "y": 35.74486039263916,
                "z": 28.212904609725967
            },
            "modelId": 1,
            "viewportIndex2d": null,
            "snapNode": 14
        },
        {
            "intersection": {
                "x": 6.363343438640598,
                "y": 50.51345608813477,
                "z": -230.43969448657225
            },
            "modelId": 1,
            "viewportIndex2d": null,
            "snapNode": 16
        }
    ],
    "type": "Distance"
}]
```

Also if you want to execute something everytime a new measure has been made, you can subscribe to **MEASUREMENT_COMPLETED_EVENT**:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.MeasureCommon.Events.MEASUREMENT_COMPLETED_EVENT, (event)=> {
   /* HERE YOUR CODE */
});
```